# Adding expanding List item to page footer band (Jasper Report)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to expand height of page footer with increasing details of a List component. I have created a test jasper report to simulate this situation.Here is the jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="footer_test" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1ab4a8b2-176a-422c-b4e2-afd6b2f5c01e">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="cd6ab13b-6111-4e9f-897b-afe354e16a24">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select t.first_name,t.last_name from test_footer as `t` limit 0,3;]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="first_name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="last_name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="4d39142a-5378-4c16-9f34-7bcfe334f8aa" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="33" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement uuid="4292c68b-c14a-4edd-9077-19164fcab508" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="33" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="dataset1" uuid="b787c354-2d90-45c7-9927-2106939bb2da">
                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:listContents height="33" width="555">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="1ca36f79-f891-4e45-83fd-c3e4cdb44b92" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{first_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="21fb2a6e-4a3d-488b-a203-136c63e3c5f0" x="322" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{last_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <line>
                                <reportElement uuid="3c56f817-e07f-4dde-9d7a-89a4bea76c2d" x="0" y="20" width="266" height="1"/>
                            </line>
                            <line>
                                <reportElement uuid="716e36f4-884a-431c-b483-a005cbaf966a" x="322" y="21" width="219" height="1"/>
                            </line>
                        </jr:listContents>
                    </jr:list>
                </componentElement>
            </frame>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="0dfbaf15-6aa5-4560-ba8f-824b35df2914" x="0" y="33" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#0033FF" backcolor="#0033CC"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="4.0" lineColor="#0033FF"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a">
                <reportElement uuid="1406ccec-0c5c-450b-a6e8-91aeda0d0619" x="0" y="34" width="166" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

But right now all items of the list doesn't get printed, probably because the footer band height is not enough. [image]

But when i increase the height of the footer band all items get printed.[image]

So, my question is, Is there a way to increase footer band height as item in List component increases.**And I need to add the List component in footer as it iterates Signature of Users.**

Comment: The footer band needs to have a fixed size. Otherwise JR does not know when to start adding the footer.

Comment: Okay so its not possible. But can we add this in detail band but print it just above footer without disabling pagination?

Comment: *can we add this in detail band but print it just above footer* - As you in general do not know which detail instance is the last on the page, I don't see this working. Or do you have some additional information, e.g. is there only enough space for one detail instance per page?

Comment: Your sample JRXML seems to indicate that the number of signers is dynamic but not dependent on the other report content. If that is correct, you can automate some way around the problem.

Comment: Yeah number of signers is dynamic. Let's say I will add it to summary band so that it gets printed after detail band but I want these signature to appear just above footer. Is that possible?. And once again I will remind you that disabling pagination to achieve this is not an option

Comment: So the number of signers is independent from the other report content. Furthermore the number of signers is limited, in your sample to a maximum of three. You could simply create 4 JRXML files optimized for 0, 1, 2, or 3 signers, and use the appropriate one.

Comment: Can you solved your problem? I have a problem like you and I don't know how to set auto height for page footer!